# Ansible authorized_key does not remove keys

Tags: ansible

I'm attempting to use Ansible to remove some keys. The command runs successfully, but does not edit the file.

```
ansible all -i inventories/staging/inventory -m authorized_key -a "user=deploy state=absent key={{ lookup('file', '/path/to/a/key.pub') }}"
```

Running this command returns the following result:

```
staging1 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "comment": null,
    "exclusive": false,
    "key": "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAxKjbpkqro9JhiEHrJSHglaZE1j5vbxNhBXNDLsooUB6w2ssLKGM9ZdJ5chCgWSpj9+OwYqNwFkJdrzHqeqoOGt1IlXsiRu+Gi3kxOCzsxf7zWss1G8PN7N93hC7ozhG7Lv1mp1EayrAwZbLM/KjnqcsUbj86pKhvs6BPoRUIovXYK28XiQGZbflak9WBVWDaiJlMMb/2wd+gwc79YuJhMSEthxiNDNQkL2OUS59XNzNBizlgPewNaCt06SsunxQ/h29/K/P/V46fTsmpxpGPp0Q42sCHczNMQNS82sJdMyKBy2Rg2wXNyaUehbKNTIfqBNKqP7J39vQ8D3ogdLLx6w== arthur@Inception.local",
    "key_options": null,
    "keyfile": "/home/deploy/.ssh/authorized_keys",
    "manage_dir": true,
    "path": null,
    "state": "absent",
    "unique": false,
    "user": "deploy",
    "validate_certs": true
}
```

The command was a success, but it doesn't show that anything changed. They key remains on the server.

Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you described occurs when you try to remove the authorized key using a non-root account different than `deploy`, i.e. without necessary permissions.

Add `--become` (`-b`) argument to the command:

```
ansible all -b -i inventories/staging/inventory -m authorized_key -a "user=deploy state=absent key={{ lookup('file', '/path/to/a/key.pub') }}"
```

---

<sup>That said, I see no justification for the `ok` status; the task should fail. This looks like a bug in Ansible to me; I filed [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/42166).</sup>